# Transferring a JPG between two Flash files

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I haven't started work in this yet, however I intend to and would like to know the best method.

There will be two screens, each powered by a separate machine.

I want to be able to move the image off one screen and it appear on the other (machine 2). The image will be captured from a webcam on machine 1.

The first idea I had was convert the image to a string, pass the string to the flash file on machine two, decode and display.

Is this possible, or is there built in function in flash or as3 that would would recommend, or even a different method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cirrus/RTMFP requires a 3rd party (Adobe) handshake step to get each swf connected, so if that's not an option for you, then:

If you have control of both machines, you might also be able to author a direct connection between the swfs with a binary socket connection. Open up a socket on a set port on the destination machine and listen for and accept connections from the origin machine, then pass the image data as a ByteArray and reconstruct it on the destination machine.

If you're able to use Cirrus and don't mind that it's beta (and that there's no guarantee that it'll be around), then it would probably be an easier solution to implement, and would definitely be a better option for realtime video transport.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Cirrus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/), which is essentially peer-to-peer technology that's meant to solve exactly this kind of problem.